# Using async/wait in dart not waiting with http package

Tags: dart, async-await

I've read the previous questions posted related to this topic but couldn't understand whats going on. I think I've done exactly the same process explained in this official dart/flutter video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmTCmDMi4BY

What I'm trying to do is very simple. I want to make an API call and need to wait until I get a response. but I can't see to get it working. Maybe my understanding on async/wait is wrong. If I check the console output I get like this

```
Staring the Program
Ending the Program
Got the questions list
[Instance of 'Question', Instance of 'Question', Instance of 'Question', Instance of 'Question', Instance of 'Question', Instance of 'Question', Instance of 'Question', Instance of 'Question', Instance of 'Question', Instance of 'Question']
```

Can someone help me with this.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  print('Staring the Program');
  getQuestions();
  print('Ending the Program');
}

void getQuestions() async {
  QuizModel qm = QuizModel();
  List<Question> questionsList = await qm.getQuestions();
  print('Got the questions list');
  print(questionsList);
}

class Question {
  String question;
  bool answer;
  Question({this.question, this.answer});
}

class QuizModel {
  var quizData;

  Future<List<Question>> getQuestions() async {
    NetworkHelper networkHelper =
        NetworkHelper('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&type=boolean');
    quizData = await networkHelper.getData();
    final List<Question> questionsList = [];
    for (final question in quizData['results']) {
      bool answer;
      question['correct_answer'] == 'True' ? answer = true : answer = false;
      questionsList
          .add(Question(question: question['question'], answer: answer));
    }
    return questionsList;
  }
}

class NetworkHelper {
  final String _url;
  NetworkHelper(this._url);

  Future<dynamic> getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(_url);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return jsonData;
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No await on getQuestions...

Answer (score 2):

`QuizModel.getQuestions()` is a future.

Your program is printing starting, calling a future, and printing ending. It does not wait for the future, getQuestions.

You can add async to your main, and await on the method call.

Comment: Thanks. Now I think it's clear. `await`s scope is only limited to `async` function.

Comment: Yes and no, without await, it returns the future itself, which you can pass around and wait for later. With await it returns the result of the future. Sometime you may want multiple futures going at once so can be handy...

Answer (score 0):

you're printing the a questionlist instance. if you want to print the questions items you need to do this

```
void getQuestions() async {
  QuizModel qm = QuizModel();
  List<Question> questionsList = await qm.getQuestions();
  print('Got the questions list');
  for(final question in questionsList){
    print(question.question);
  }
}
```

instead of

```
void getQuestions() async {
  QuizModel qm = QuizModel();
  List<Question> questionsList = await qm.getQuestions();
  print('Got the questions list');
  print(questionsList);
}
```

Comment: I'm just printing it as reference. My question though why `Ending the Program` is printed prior to `Got the questions list`

Answer (score 0):

```
I/flutter (18222): Staring the Program
I/flutter (18222): Got the questions list
I/flutter (18222): [Instance of 'Question', Instance of 'Question', Instance of 'Question', Instance of 'Question', Instance of 'Question', Instance of 'Question', Instance of 'Question', Instance of 'Question', Instance of 'Question', Instance of 'Question']
I/flutter (18222): Ending the Program
```

if you need to get this print u must replace this

```
void main() {
  print('Staring the Program');
  getQuestions();
  print('Ending the Program');
}

void getQuestions() async {
  QuizModel qm = QuizModel();
  List<Question> questionsList = await qm.getQuestions();
  print('Got the questions list');
  print(questionsList);
}
```

with this

```
void main()async {
  print('Staring the Program');
  await getQuestions();
  print('Ending the Program');
}

Future<void> getQuestions() async {
  QuizModel qm = QuizModel();
  List<Question> questionsList = await qm.getQuestions();
  print('Got the questions list');
  print(questionsList);
}
```